# how to write/rewrite in a <p> using a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

was hoping if anyone could help. I would like to be able to have it that whenever the arrays I pass into the function change it will display these values in a paragraph tag.
At the moment it doesn't rewrite it and I want it to display like it's steps (i.e 1. ... 2. ...) but it doesn't update the step number or take a new line either. This function is called in another function.

The code so far is:

```
//javascript code
//cred & grade are arrays
function breakdown(cred, grade){
    var change = document.getElementById('bdown'); //'bdown' is the id of the <p>
    var to;
    var a = 1;
    var x = 0;          

    for(var b = 0; b<cred.length; b++){
        //alert(a)

        to += a + ". (" + cred[b] + " x " + grade[b] + ")" + "<br /"; //show the step number and the values then take a new line
        a++; //increment the step number

        change.innerHTML=bdown.innerHTML.replace(change.textContent,to ); //wish to change <p>
    }
}

//html code
// the paragraph wish to change
<div id="how"; style="color:white;display: none">
    <p id="bdown"></p>
</div>
```

Using code:

```
var to = "";
for(var b = 0; b<cred.length; b++){
    to += "(" + grade[b] + " x " + cred[b] + ") + ";}

... .getElementById('').innerHTML = to;
```

Expecting output with cred = [10, 20], grade = [11, 21]:

1. (10 x 11) + (20 x 21) <-- this expands when arrays have values added to them.

Actual output:

1. (undefined) <-- doesn't change

I don't have jquery running on my coding platform so javascript code would be really great :)

Comment: Also any particular reason you cannot add jQuery as I'm sure it would save you a ton of hassle in other areas?

Comment: Can you post the code you have that calls the breakdown function? Also there seems to be a small typo in your code `"<br /"` should be `"<br />"`

Comment: I'm creating a desktop/mobile app not a web application and the platform I'm using won't support it for some strange reason :/ I do realise that you can do awesome stuff with jquery though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a list of numbered steps, you want to use the `ol` tag.

Obviously, you'll want to populate the `ol` tag with `li` tags :P

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and see how it goes :)

Comment: the code in the for loo[ doesn't work with my program. I want to create a string that takes each value in the arrays and put it in "( x )" like (10 x 40) + (20 x 11) - the numbers being the values in cred and grade respectively. It keeps printing out as undefined and doesn't change :/

Comment: Can you add the output you are expecting, and the source you are now using.

Comment: haha just as i post it I fix it. It's all working now. thank you for all your help :D

Comment: Ah super, that's the way it nearly always happen.  You're explaining it and that makes you see the problem.  Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simplified version to see if it works? Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("bdown").innerHTML=to;
```